# Selenium - Facing issue in uploading the image in the profile pic

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Unable to upload the image.After click on the "add photo" button browser popup displayed. But its not taking the path of the file and not clicking the open button.

`WebElement uploadElement=ep.Addphoto();
uploadElement.click();
uploadElement.sendKeys("Path_of_the_image")`;

Comment: Cane you make sure that the locator of your uploadElement is targetting the `input` as `file` and not as `button`

Comment: In the HTML snippet Only the class name found for my upload element. I used locator CSS selector.

Comment: Can you provide the DOM structure and your CSS selector used?

Comment: CSS Selector used: ".material-icons.large-font.text-muted"                    DOM Structure: <label class="d-flex flex-column cursor-pointer justify-content-center profile-photo  garage-photos grey-bg" xpath="1">
<i class="material-icons large-font text-muted">photo_camera</i>
<p class="mb-0">Add Photo</p>
<p class="mb-0">(optional) </p>
<input class=" display-none " type="file" name="profile_pic" id="profile_pic" accept="image/*">
</label>

Comment: Can you target the `input` element instead in your selector?

Comment: I tried with the inputs elements. In ChroPath its displayed like "1 element matching'. But in the UI page nothing is highlighted.

Comment: @Ramya Please try the code in my answer below. Please let me know if there is any error once you try the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='profile_pic']")).sendKeys("absolute-path-of-image-file")
```

Can you please try the above code ?
No need to click on the element. Directly use the above code to sendKeys to the input element.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the element is present in the dom structure but not visible on the UI. As you can see in your DOM which is as follows:

```
<label class="d-flex flex-column cursor-pointer justify-content-center profile-photo garage-photos grey-bg" xpath="1"> 
<i class="material-icons large-font text-muted">photo_camera</i> 
<p class="mb-0">Add Photo</p> <p class="mb-0">(optional) </p> 
<input class=" display-none " type="file" name="profile_pic" id="profile_pic" accept="image/*"> 
</label>
```

The input class has `display-none`